# How to ensure placeholder text is not saved as value in the database in swift 4

Tags: swift

I wanted to have a textview which is optional and bears a placeholder that directs users to type some text. However, when the user submits the form without typing a text, the placeholder text is saved as value in the database.

Comment: Hi @Formadev please, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and then como back with some code for we help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're setting the text property to whatever you'd like the placeholder to be. The easiest way would be to do a simple check to see if the text value is equal to the placeholder:

```
theTextView.text = "Your placeholder..."
```

Then at the point you do your save actions

```
if theTextView.text != "Your placeholder..." {
    // Add it to the data to be saved
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use placeholder parameter for placeholder text.

```
theTextView.placeholder = "Your placeholder text."
```

Use text parameter for your text input.

```
theTextView.text = "Your text data."
```